# how to make the conditional ng-class work

Tags: angularjs

Without defining an variable in controller, just put it in html, like the `reverse'`:

```
<span reverse='0' ng-class="{'sort-ascent':reverse=='1','sort-descent':reverse=='0'}">
```

I have some logics to change `reverse` to `'0'` or `'1'` somewhere else, How can I make the conditional `ng-class` work?

As the default `reverse` is `'0'`, I expect `ng-class` use the class `sort-descent`, but it doesn't work.

I have a custom directive, in its link function I generate a table through html.

I am trying to put a 'sorting' sign on column headers.

Maybe this is a very stupid question.

Comment: Sorry, i just updated the question

Answer (score 2):

Use `ng-init` instead:

```
<span ng-init="reverse='0'" ng-class="{'sort-ascent':reverse=='1','sort-descent':reverse=='0'}">
```

The attribute `reverse='0'` on its own will not initialize `reverse` to `'0'`.

`ng-init` will initialize `reverse` and when you change `reverse` in the controller it will adjust the value.

Comment: Thanks,I tried, it works. I am going to try to get access to 'reverse' from html tag.

Comment: You could always default it in the controller to '0'.  What are you trying to achieve with accessing via the attribute?

Comment: I updated the question with more background. If I put this in my html file, it works. Because the whole table's html is generated in my directive's link function, this seems not working for my table header.

Comment: Another approach would be to set the regular class attribute to the default class (sort-descend). Initially, angular will respect the class, and then switch it based on ng-class, later.